# import openzeplin files into contract

Tags: truffle, erc-20, openzeppelin, verify

For an ERC-20 Pauseable, mintable, capped contract I directly used files like below.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControlEnumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Contract has been verified using truffle with multiple files and it works fine on testnet. Question is, will it be an issue
for exchanges to list this coin when I push contract on main net to include files directly instead of copy pasting code in one file?

Comment: What do you mean by "issue"  and "exchanges"? Please update the question body with clarifications.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I meant to list coin on exchanges like Bittrex, is it issue to include files directly instead of copy pasting code?

Comment: Centralized exchanges like Bittrex couldn't care less about how you import your external contracts in your Solidity code base. Just make sure to verify the source code of the contract on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/). See my tool [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol) for that, or the [hardhat-etherscan](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/tree/master/packages/hardhat-etherscan) plugin if you're a Hardhat user (I recommend becoming one, it's better than Truffle).